# Session Error from Console Command

Tags: plugin-development

I created a simplistic Console Command class in my plugin folder containing this function:

```
public function actionTest () {
    craft()->templates->renderString('index');
}
```

When I run the command:

*./yiic < plugin > Test*

I get the follwing error message:

```
Property "Craft\ConsoleApp.session" is not defined.
exception 'CException' with message 'Property "Craft\ConsoleApp.session" is not defined.' in /Users/< username >/Sites/< project >/craft/app/framework/base/CComponent.php:130
```

Thoughts? The end goal here is to be able to render HTML emails and them at specific intervals, but for some reason when using craft services, I get session errors.

Answer (score 1):

The OP was running an older version of Craft. Resolved the issue by updating to the latest.

Answer (score 0):

I received an email from craft:

> Hey Frederick,
>
> This looks to be a bug in Craft. We're looking into it and will let you know what we find!
>
> -Brad